# Why do we need to call thread.start() instead of thread.run()?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java thread - run() and start() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027495/java-thread-run-and-start-methods)

I made a program which uses threading---

```
public class ThreadTest{    
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        MyThread newthread=new MyThread();
        Thread t=new Thread(newthread);
        t.start();
        for(int x=0;x<10; x++){
            System.out.println("Main"+x)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
            System.out.println("Thread"+x);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is that ... why do we use the "Thread" class and create it's object and pass the "MyThread" calls in it's constructor? can't we call the run method of the "MyThread" object by creating it's object and calling the run method?

( i.e  `MyThread newthread=new MyThread(); and then newthread.run();`   )

What's the reason for creating tread objects and passing the MyThread class in it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `MyThread` class is *not* a thread. It is an ordinary class that implements `Runnable` and has a method called `run`.

If you call the `run` method directly it will run the code on the *current* thread, not on a *new* thread.

---

To start a new thread you create a new instead of the `Thread` class, give it an object that implements `Runnable`, and then call the `start` method on the thread object. When the thread starts, it will call the `run` method on your object for you.

Another way to start a thread is to subclass `Thread` and override its `run` method. Again to start it you must instantiate it and call the `start` method, not the `run` method.The reason is the same: if you call `run` directly it will run the method in the current thread.

See [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for more information about starting new threads in Java.

Comment: What i want to know is... why would i want to create multiple threads instead of just i thread i.e Main thread ?

Comment: @IamA are you saying that Java does not need the ability to create multiple threads?

Comment: @IamAPseudo-Intellectual: If you want to do more than one thing at the same time you can use multiple threads. If you use only one thread, when you call `run` your  thread cannot do anything else until the method completes. This isn't a problem with your toy example since your method only a fraction of a second to run. But if the method could take several minutes to run it would cause your program to hang and be unresponsive to user input.

Comment: @MarkByers- Thanks... got it .. multi threading :)

Comment: @ MДΓΓ БДLL- I'm new to programming.. sorry if i sound like a Novice..

Answer (score 0):

start() ->

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread.
>   From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

For me, only JVM know when give some memory of your program to thread.
So we have a standart to use something like this:

```
new Thread().start();
```