# I am calling start first and then run, but the output is like 2 different threads being run

Tags: java, multithreading

I am calling `start` first and then `run`. When I run first `run()` then `start()`, `run` is being treated as a method and completely runs and then `start` is called, but in this way I am having the output as:

> 0Thread-1 
>   0Thread-0 
>   1Thread-1 
>   1Thread-0 
>   2Thread-0 
>   2Thread-1 
>   3Thread-1 
>   3Thread-0 
>   4Thread-1 
>   4Thread-0

Why, once run is called, doesn't it completely run?

```
public class basic extends Thread {
  public void run (){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println(i+ this.getName());
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    basic x= new basic();
    basic y=new basic();
    x.start();
    y.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, i is not *like* 2 different threads being executed. It **is** 2 different threads being executed. The current thread, executing the run() method, and the started thread, executing it, too, concurrently, in a different thread. How is that surprising?

Answer (score 0):

Thread.start() is the proper way to Start a Thread.

```
x.start();
y.start();
```

will start 2 new threads.

```
x.run();
y.run();
```

Will just execute the code inside your thread under the actual main Thread.
This is a common mistake.

[Already mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027495/please-explain-the-output-from-thread-run-and-start-methods)

[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674174/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run)

Comment: i use camelCase and use small letter for one word,thanks.my question is little different

Comment: Ok , sorry.Did this work for you?Have you understood the difference between run and start?

Comment: If you want you can check those free tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JceAHRlQsqc

Comment: Well it is.It was completed , counting from 0 to 4 , no?